# What table and column contain the date a contact was added?

Tags: contacts, database, data-model

I'm trying to determine the correct table and column to check the data a contact was added to the civicrm-contact table. What is the best method for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date_created` on the `civicrm_contact` table.

Comment: There is no column called date_created in civicrm_contact. We are on 4.1.5

Comment: Well there's your problem :)  Is there a reason to stay on Civi 4.1.5?  That's an out-of-date and insecure version - and of course created_date was added in 4.3.

Comment: No budget to upgrade yet. I can look at the first row created in the subscription_history table which is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Check the table civicrm_log. The column entity_table will contain civicrm_contact and the column entity_id the id of the contact you are looking for. Does that help? If you want more specific information you need to explain what you are trying to do :-)

Comment: I am selecting the created column for the in last user created in Drupal and want to show the date the corresponding CiviCRM record was created.